Call GENUUID from COBOL AS400
GENUUID is  the IBM provided procedure. I can find the example of calling GENUUID from RPG, but need to add _(Underscore) in the name
EXTPRC('_GENUUID')
but I don't know how to do this in COBOL.
I tried using underscore in the COBOL call command, compile ends in error saying invalid program name.
appreciate any help. Thanks!

Generating UUIDs in COBOL using IBM's GENUUID procedure Generate Universal Unique Identifier (GENUUID)

Found this in the i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit
Note that at v7.3 IBM enhanced GENUUID to support type 4 UUIDs.  If you want to generate type 4 UUIDs use this template ( I think, my COBOL is very rusty and was never used on an IBM midrange system). Note that COBOL doesn't support a 1 byte binary, thus pic x(1) you'll want to move x'04' to this version field.
   01 uuid-t is typedef.
      05 bytes-in  pic 9(9) usage comp-4.
      05 bytes-out pic 9(9) usage comp-4.
      05 version   pic x(1).
      05 reserved  pic x(7).
      05 uuid      pic x(16).


 /**
  * This file is part of i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.
  *
  * Copyright (C) 2010, 2011  Junlei Li.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  * (at your option) any later version.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  * GNU General Public License for more details.
  *
  * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  * along with i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  */

 /**
  * @file cbl002.cblle
  *
  * Test of:
  *  - _GENUUID
  *  - _PROPB
  */
   process
       NOMONOPRC.

   id division.
   program-id. cbl002.

   environment division.
   configuration section.
   special-names.
       copy mih-lnktyp.

   data division.
   working-storage section.
       copy mih-spt.
   01 result pic x(32).
   01 tmpl   type uuid-t.
   01 uuid-len pic 9(9) usage comp-4 value 32.

   procedure division.
   main-pgm.

       move all x"00" to tmpl.
       move 32 to bytes-in of tmpl.
       call "_GENUUID" using
           by reference tmpl.

       call program "CVTHC" using
           by reference result
           by reference uuid of tmpl
           by reference uuid-len.
       display "UUID generated: " result.

   see-you.
       stop run.
  *
  * Output of cbl002 might be the following:
  * UUID generated: 8E47800184071945AC820004AC117E94
  *

The COPY files
 /**
  * This file is part of i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.
  *
  * Copyright (C) 2010, 2011  Junlei Li.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  * (at your option) any later version.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  * GNU General Public License for more details.
  *
  * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  * along with i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  */

 /**
  * @file mih-spt.cblleinc
  *
  * Machine interface support instructions.
  */

  *A   B

 /**
  * Instruction template of GENUUID.
  */
   01 uuid-t is typedef.
      05 bytes-in  pic 9(9) usage comp-4.
      05 bytes-out pic 9(9) usage comp-4.
      05 reserved  pic x(8).
      05 uuid      pic x(16).

 /**
  * @BIF _GENUUID (Generate Universal Unique Identifier (GENUUID))
  *
  * @example test/cbl002.cblle
  */
  *    call "_GENUUID" using DS-of-type-uuid-t.


 /**
  * This file is part of i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.
  *
  * Copyright (C) 2010, 2011  Junlei Li.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  * (at your option) any later version.
  *
  * i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  * GNU General Public License for more details.
  *
  * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  * along with i5/OS Programmer's Toolkit.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  */

 /**
  * @file mih-lnktyp.cblleinc
  *
  * Linkage type clauses for all system builtins are place here.
  *
  * @attention Make sure to copy this header in the SPECIAL-NAMES
  *            paragraph of your COBOL program.
  */

  *A   B

  * Compuation instructions.
       linkage type is sys for
           "_CMPSWP1"
           "_CMPSWP2"
           "_CMPSWP4"
           "_CMPSWP8"
           "_CPRDATA"
           "_DCPDATA"
           "_TSTBTS"
           "_CLRBTS"
           "_SETBTS"
           "_CVTEFN"
           "_CPYECLAP"
           "_LBCPYNV"
           "_LBCPYNVR"
           "_ACOS"
           "_ANDCSTR"
           "_ANDSTR"
           "_ASIN"
           "_ATAN"
           "_ATANH"
           "__strlen"
           "__strcmp"
           "_STRNCMPNULL"
           "_CMPTOPAD"
           "_COMSTR"
           "_COS"
           "_COSH"
           "_COT"
           "_CPYBYTES"
           "_CPYBO"
           "__strcpy"
           "_STRNCPYNULL"
           "_STRNCPYNULLPAD"
           "_EEXP"
           "_FINDBYTE"
           "_MEMCHR"
           "_STRCHRNULL"
           "_LN"
           "__memcmp"
           "__memcpy"
           "_MEMMOVE"
           "_MPYADD"
           "_MPYSUB"
           "_ORSTR"
           "_POWER"
           "_PROPB"
           "__memset"
           "_RETCA"
           "_SETCA"
           "_SCANX"
           "_SIN"
           "_SINH"
           "_TAN"
           "_TANH"
           "_TESTRPL"
           "_TESTSUBSET"
           "_XLATEB"
           "_XLATEB1"
           "_XORSTR"
           .

  * Date/Time/Timestamp instructions.
       linkage type is sys for "_CTD"
                               "_CDD"
                               "_CTSD".

  * Pointer/name resolution instructions.
       linkage type is sys for "_CMPPTRA"
                               "_CMPPTRT"
                               "_MATPTRL"
                               "_RSLVSP2"
                               "_RSLVSP4"
                               "_SETSPPFP".

  * Data pointer related instructions
       linkage type is sys for "_SETDP"
                               "_SETDPADR".

  * Space Management Instructions.
       linkage type is sys for "_CRTS"
                               "_DESS"
                               "_MATS"
                               "_MODS1"
                               "_MODS2".

  * Machine Interface support instructions.
       linkage type is sys for "_GENUUID".

  * Program Management instrucions.
       linkage type is sys for "_MATPGMNM".

  * Program execution instructions.
       linkage type is sys for "_NPMPARMLISTADDR"
                               "_MODASA".

